# Calling Java from Excel VBA and return results

Tags: java, vba

I am wondering how to use java for complex calculations which need very much time in VBA. Is it possible? Does this make sense? How would I have to call my java code and how do I get the results?

Greets, poeschlorn

Comment: Last time I checked, the easiest way was to expose your Java API via a web service. The other route was to wrap your Java code in a COM API. Bottom line: it was not super straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Write your java code in a webservice and call it from a VBA code.